# Python, appending all links, titles, and body text into one array or json file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

help, I'm grabbing multiple href url links from a website and trying to append each title and body text of the urls into another array. however when I run something similar to this, I only grab one title, with all the text of the other links together.

```
request = requests.get(url)
somecontents = request.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(somecontents, "html.parser")
soup.prettify()
gethref = urllinks.get("href")

if gethref is not None and\
  "http" in gethref and\
  "photo" not in gethref and\
  "img" not in gethref:
    page_links = []
    tags_in_link = gethref
    page_links.append(tags_in_link)
    hrefdataset = ','.join(page_links)

for each_link in i:
    website_header_title = soup.title.string
    parse_title = re.sub('[^A-Za-z]+', ' ', website_header_title)
    time.sleep(.05)

    done = grab_web_text(each_link)

    testintry = []
    testintry.append("Website Title: " + parse_title + "," + " ")
    text = testintry.append("Body: " + done)
```

I would like each link in: how can I format it into this from what I have?

```
[{"Website Title: " "title", "Body: " "Body}, 
[{"Website Title: " "title", "Body: " "Body}, 
[{"Website Title: " "title", "Body: " "Body}, 
[{"Website Title: " "title", "Body: " "Body}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of dictionaries like this:

```
def get_link_info(l):
    parse_title = re.sub('[^A-Za-z]+', ' ', website_header_title)
    done = grab_web_text(each_link)
    return (parse_title, done)

print([{t: d} for t, d in (get_link_info(i) for i in links)])
```

How does this work?

1. `for i in links` is a loop over all the links.
2. `get_link_info` returns a tuple containing `title` and `done
3. `for t, d in (...)` is a loop over resulting tuples
4. `{t: d} for t, d in (...)` is a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)
5. Outer `[]` creates a list from generator.